# Cannot Connect Keycloak docker to SQL database

Tags: sql-server, keycloak

I'm trying to connect Keycloak with docker to a SQL Server database located on another server, but I'm not getting a connection.
This is the command I'm typing:

```
docker run --name keycloak \
  --net keycloak-network \
  -p 8080:8080 \
  -e DB_VENDOR=mssql \
  -e DB_USER=*** \
  -e DB_PASSWORD=*** \
  -e DB_ADDR=172.... \
  -e DB_DATABASE=Keycloak \
  -e KEYCLOAK_USER=user \
  -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=password \
  jboss/keycloak
```

Could someone help me to solve it please.

Apparently it could be some SSL and RSA 1024 bitkey error

```
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Certificates do not conform to algorithm constraints
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkAlgorithmConstraints(SSLContextImpl.java:1681)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkAdditionalTrust(SSLContextImpl.java:1606)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextImpl.java:1550)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:638)
        ... 78 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Algorithm constraints check failed on keysize limits: RSA 1024 bit key used with certificate: CN=SSL_Self_Signed_Fallback
        at java.base/sun.security.util.DisabledAlgorithmConstraints$KeySizeConstraint.permits(DisabledAlgorithmConstraints.java:889)
        at java.base/sun.security.util.DisabledAlgorithmConstraints$Constraints.permits(DisabledAlgorithmConstraints.java:507)
        at java.base/sun.security.util.DisabledAlgorithmConstraints.permits(DisabledAlgorithmConstraints.java:247)
        at java.base/sun.security.util.DisabledAlgorithmConstraints.permits(DisabledAlgorithmConstraints.java:193)
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.AlgorithmChecker.check(AlgorithmChecker.java:292)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkAlgorithmConstraints(SSLContextImpl.java:1677)
        ... 81 more
```

These are the errors that appear.

Comment: Why not? What's the error message? Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73300223/edit) your question to include the error message(s) - as text, not screen shots.

Comment: Have you already created the `Keycloak` database on the target SQL Server? Does the DB_USER/DB_PASSWORD combination already exist as an SQL Login on the target SQL Server? Is that SQL Login's default_database set to the `Keycloak` database? Is the SQL Login mapped to a Database User in the `Keycloak` database? Does that Database User have db_owner privileges? That last one is important because Keycloak uses Liquibase to deploy schema, so it needs sufficient access to do that.

Comment: SQL Server gets installed with a self-signed X.509 certificate which gets used to secure encrypted connections (and passwords during login). Seems like you're trying to connect to an older version of SQL Server that only has a 1024-bit certificate. Try connecting to a different SQL Server of a more recent version or, if that's not possible, investigate installing a new certificate with at least 2048-bits on the target server, ref: [Certificate Management (SQL Server Configuration Manager)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/manage-certificates).

Comment: In this case I would have to ask the database administrator to install this certificate on this old version of SQL Server, correct?